tiles-definitions for apache tiles whether can we use https?
Below is a sample code from one of my tiles.xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>

Here if you notice, the url starts with http:// Even in official documentation, the example is written like this. https://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/basic/pages.html
Now, the problem is I am using Tomcat9 with Liferay 7.4 version. And in my tomcat server in production, I need to disable all traffic (inbound + outbound) from port 80. Once I do that, in my application during runtime, I get below error
ERROR com.liferay.portletmvc4spring.DispatcherPortlet - Could not complete request
org.apache.tiles.definition.DefinitionsFactoryException: I/O Error reading definitions.
        at org.apache.tiles.definition.digester.DigesterDefinitionsReader.read(DigesterDefinitionsReader.java:331) ~[tiles-core-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
        at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromResource(BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:150) ~[tiles-core-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
        at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadRawDefinitionsFromResources(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:239) ~[tiles-core-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
        at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadRawDefinitionsFromResources(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:230) ~[tiles-core-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
        at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadRawDefinitionsFromResources(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:230) ~[tiles-core-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
        at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromResources(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:208) ~[tiles-core-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
        at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:197) ~[tiles-core-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
        at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitions(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:68) ~[tiles-core-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]


I am thinking, tomcat is trying to download the definitions file from this url dynamically when the application loads JSP and at that time, as port 80 is blocked, it is giving this exception.
So, my question is

What is a graceful way of handling this if in documentation itself
http:// is mentioned?
Why don't all people face similar issue if this is the case?


Why do you think blocking your server port 80 has anything to do with an URL from another server? What happens if you enable port 80? Is the error related to this file? Which version of Apache tiles?

Because outbound traffic is disabled on port 80 from my server. So, http request would not go out. If I keep it open, it is unsecure connection. So, not recommended for production system.

Apache Tiles 2.1 is an ancient release and the entire Tiles project is retired since 2018. Maybe they never got to implement XML external entity vulnerability prevention. I recommend to migrate to some newer framework and supported framework.
In the meantime you could download the DTD file into your project and reference it with a local URL instead of a remote one.
Another option is to just change the URL to HTTPS: https://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd which is working right now. At least while the Apache Foundation doesn't shutdown the site. You can not depend on external resources being online forever, specially with a retired project.

Your point is correct. But I am facing similar issue even with Apache Tiles 3.0. The official documentation again points to unsecured http url.

In general I have a question, all these dtd files, why the organizations expose over http (As I saw everywhere)? And I assume all the prod web servers would block unsecured http traffic. Then how all the production grade projects in the world are even working?

Tiles 3.x is from 2016-2017 so very old by today standards. Seems it still has the same issue. Get out of using such an old and unsupported product as soon as you can. Also most if not all public web servers now redirect traffic automatically from HTTP to HTTPS.
